# How rewrite menu on Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue. I wrote a menu script on jquery. Now I want to rewrite this script on Vue. The menu should always be on one line. If the item of menu does not fit, add a class 'is-hidden'. How to add a method so that a class that does not fit menu items is added 'is-hidden'?

Jquery variant menu:

```js
$(function() {
  var base = '.menu';

  $(base).each(function() {
    var component = $(this);
    var menuItems = component.children(base + '__item');

    function calc() {
      var menuWidth = Math.floor(component.innerWidth());
      var menuItemsCounter = 0;

      menuItems.each(function(i, el) {
        var menuItemWidth = Math.floor($(el).outerWidth());

        if (menuItemsCounter + menuItemWidth > menuWidth - 10) {
          $(el).addClass('is-hidden')
        } else {
          $(el).removeClass('is-hidden')
          menuItemsCounter += menuItemWidth;
        }
      });
    }

    calc();
    $(window).on('resize', calc);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;

}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Vue</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Angular</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">React</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">HTML</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">CSS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Javascript</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">C#</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">C++</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Python</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Java</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Ruby</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">PHP</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Laravel</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Chrome</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Firefox</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Webpack</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Gulp</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a href="#">Grunt</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Vue variant menu:

```js
const menu = {
  data() {
    return {
      menu: [
        { title: 'Vue' },
        { title: 'Angular' },
        { title: 'React' },
        { title: 'HTML' },
        { title: 'CSS' },
        { title: 'Javascript' },
        { title: 'C#' },
        { title: 'C++' },
        { title: 'Python' },
        { title: 'Java' },
        { title: 'Ruby' },
        { title: 'PHP' },
        { title: 'Laravel' },
        { title: 'Chrome' },
        { title: 'Firefox' },
        { title: 'Webpack' },
        { title: 'Gulp' },
        { title: 'Grunt' },
        { title: 'Vue' },
        { title: 'Angular' },
        { title: 'React' },
        { title: 'HTML' },
        { title: 'CSS' },
        { title: 'Javascript' },
        { title: 'C#' },
        { title: 'C++' },
        { title: 'Python' },
        { title: 'Java' },
        { title: 'Ruby' },
        { title: 'PHP' },
        { title: 'Laravel' },
        { title: 'Chrome' },
        { title: 'Firefox' },
        { title: 'Webpack' },
        { title: 'Gulp' },
        { title: 'Grunt' },
      ],
      menuWidth: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    currentLastVisibleItemIndex() {
      return this.menu.length - 1;
    },
    updateWidth: function () {
      this.menuWidth = window.innerWidth;
    },
    calc: function () {
      // this.menu.forEach((el, index) => {
      //    console.log(el, this.$refs.menu[index]);
      // });
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWidth);
    this.updateWidth();
    this.calc();
  },
}

Vue.createApp(menu).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: black;

}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app" class="app">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li v-for="item in menu" :key="item.title" ref="menu">
      <a href="#">{{item.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <p>
    <b>Menu width:</b> {{menuWidth}}
  </p>
</div>
```